# Execução do script após clicar num link

Tags: php, array, session

Estou aprendendo PHP e o meu desafio é fazer um Carrinho de Compras usando SESSION.

Dentro da minha lógica, estou tentando executar um `array_push`, depois de clicar no link "inserir produto no carrinho", a partir da página do produto e desta forma, "preencher" o `array` criado através de SESSION e que está na página "Carrinho", ao mesmo tempo em que sou direcionado para esta página.

É possível?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um `redirect` para o a página de referência usando o `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Depois de fazer a sua lógico de adicionar o produto na sessão apenas redirecione

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```